# why REDIS SERVER clears memory as i push data?

Tags: redis, node-redis

As I am taking the learning curve in REDIS I developd a simple application that consumes market data of goverment bonds, and for each price, it routine ask a webservice for bonds analytics at that price.

Analytics is provided by a api webservice that might be hitted several times as prices arrives every second. The response is a json payload like this one `{"md":2.9070078608390455,"paridad":0.7710514176999993,"price":186.0,"ticker":"GO26","tir":0.10945225427543438,"vt":241.22904871224668, "price":185}`

My strategy with REDIS is to cache that payload in string format with a key formet by ticker + price (i.e "GO26185). That way I reduce service hits and also query time response. So from here, if a value is not on REDIS, i ask to the APi. If not, i ask to REDIS.

The problem i have is that when running this routine, as long as i PUSH different KEY VALUE pair on REDIS, the one I already have in memory disapears.
i,em. (dbsize, increases as soon as i push information, but decreases when there are no new values).

Although I set expiration to one day (in seconds):

```
await client.set(
                rediskey,
                JSON.stringify(response.data)
                ,{
                EX: 86399,
                }
            );
```

Is there any configuration I might be messing to tell redis to persist that data and avoid clearing the cache randomly?

Just to clarify, a glance on how SET  keys dissapears while registering new ones:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> dbsize
(integer) 946;
127.0.0.1:6379> dbsize
(integer) 1046;
127.0.0.1:6379> dbsize
(integer) 1048;
127.0.0.1:6379> dbsize
(integer) 1048;
127.0.0.1:6379> dbsize
(integer) 0 << Here all my keys have dissapeared
```

Comment: This could be a purge of expired records triggered by a write.

Answer (score 0):

I am replying my own answer. The problem was that I didn't block redis port and a hacker was connecting to my redis server, causing it to reset. Seems it was using the replicatio nodes.

Comment: Do you have `AUTH` set on your server? If not, fix *immediately*.

Comment: The real answer here would be - nothing to do with programming. This is admin issue